# Meaning of "taking a lot of winning over"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I'll try to give the context:

> I will be flown home [after having fled overseas and getting in
>   trouble there]... My husband will **take a lot of winning over**, but
>   sooner or later he will take me back, and forgive me.

Googling produces five to a dozen results, depending on the tense applied, and I've failed to deduce what exactly the phrase means.

Comment: It’s analogous to “take a lot of _strength_”. The assertion is that the spouse needs to try hard to win him over.

Comment: It's going to take a lot of effort to win the husband over.

Comment: "Winning over" is an idiom, roughly meaning "convincing".

Comment: "Persuasion."  Look up the phrase "win over" for meaning and usage.

Comment: @HotLicks More than that, actually, in most cases.